# How can I generate output in Word for correlation tables in Stata?

Tags: ms-word, stata, correlation

I want to generate an output for my correlation table so I can use it in Word. The only command I found is `mkcorr`, which only generates an output I can copy in Excel, but not in Word.
I need a correlation table in Paper style ( with means, standard deviation, correlation and significance label).

Comment: You're best off posting this on Statalist, for two reasons. First, you show no code here, so your question is marginal for this forum. Second, there are all kinds of user-written extras that support MS Word output, but probably more experience among Statalist users of which might fit your problem. I don't use any of them, so can't advise specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First, the help file of `mkcorr` says that you can produce the output in Word:

"*mkcorr produces a correlation table in a format that is easy to import into a
    spreadsheet or word processing document*"

Second, `mkcorr` does what you want. It includes  means, standard deviation, correlation and significance label (and also minimum and maximum).

Here is an example:

```
sysuse auto 
mkcorr price mpg, log(C:\Users\Vista\Desktop\auto.doc) replace means sig cdec(2) mdec(2)
```

However, the output in Word needs some manipulation compared with that in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with estout/esttab/estpost after installing it:

```
capture ssc install estout 
sysuse auto
estpost correlate price mpg weight 
esttab using corr.rtf
```

This is pretty basic looking, but you can make it a lot more fancy after looking at some examples [here](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/estpost.html).